# Syntax error on line 6 'if/elif statements' and 'and/or statements'

Tags: python, if-statement

I am continually getting a syntax error on line 6 when trying to run this code. I've tried messing with the indentation and have browsed related questions on this site to no avail. Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thank you!

```
#program that reads month and day and outputs season
input_month = input()
input_day = int(input())

#input reading for spring
if ((input_month == 'March') and (20 <= input_day <= 31))
or ((input_month == 'June') and (1 <= input_day <= 20))
    print('Spring')

#input reading for summer
elif (input_month == 'June') and (21 <= input_day <= 30) 
or (input_month == 'September') and (1 <= input_day <= 30)
    print('Summer')

#input reading for Autumn
elif (input_month == 'September') and (22 <= input_day <= 30) 
or (input_month == 'December') and (1 <= input_day <= 20)
    print('Autumn')

#input reading for winter
elif (input_month == 'December') and (21 <= input_day <= 31) 
or (input_month == 'January') and (1 <= input_day <= 31)
or (input_month == 'February') and (1 <= input_day <= 28)
or (input_month == 'March') and (1 <= input_day <= 19)
    print('Winter')
```

Edit: the error reads 'EOL error' which has in the past meant that I didn't define a variable or didn't write the variable correctly. This doesn't seem to be the case though.

Thank you all for the help!!

Here's the updated, working code including all months:

```
#program that reads month and day and outputs season
input_month = input()
input_day = int(input())

#input reading for spring
if input_month == 'March' and 20 <= input_day <= 31\
or input_month == 'April' and 1 <= input_day <= 30\
or input_month == 'May' and 1 <= input_day <= 31\
or input_month == 'June' and 1 <= input_day <= 20:
    print('Spring')

#input reading for summer
elif input_month == 'June' and 21 <= input_day <= 30\
or input_month == 'July' and 1 <= input_day <= 31\
or input_month == 'August' and 1 <= input_day <= 31\
or input_month == 'September' and 1 <= input_day <= 30:
    print('Summer')

#input reading for Autumn
elif input_month == 'September' and 22 <= input_day <= 30\
or input_month == 'October' and 1 <= input_day <= 31\
or input_month == 'November' and 1 <= input_day <= 30\
or input_month == 'December' and 1 <= input_day <= 20:
    print('Autumn')

#input reading for winter
elif input_month == 'December' and 21 <= input_day <= 31\
or input_month == 'January' and 1 <= input_day <= 31\
or input_month == 'February' and 1 <= input_day <= 28\
or input_month == 'March' and 1 <= input_day <= 19:
    print('Winter')

#if input is not valid
else:
    print('Invalid')
```

Comment: Don't forget about the `:` after every if/elif/else statement.

Comment: Oh my goodness, could it be as simple as adding the colon? I've been staring at this too long apparently lol.

Comment: @DemianWolf OP _could_ do it as a multiline statement, but each line would need to end with a backslash \

Comment: As far as the multiline goes, is there not a way to have and/or statements on multiple lines? I just think the code looks sloppy with the lines so long. Would the easiest way to do this be to just create multiple elif statements for each season?

Comment: @G.Anderson yes, but \ is necessary, while Drkdeibs didn't use it.

Comment: Ya'll rock BTW! Always so quick and helpful with the responses:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a syntactically correct code (with backslashes):

```
input_month = input()
input_day = int(input())

if input_month == 'March' and 20 <= input_day <= 31 or input_month \
    == 'June' and 1 <= input_day <= 20:
    print('Spring')
elif input_month == 'June' and 21 <= input_day <= 30 or input_month \
    == 'September' and 1 <= input_day <= 30:
    print('Summer')
elif input_month == 'September' and 22 <= input_day <= 30 \
    or input_month == 'December' and 1 <= input_day <= 20:
    print('Autumn')
elif input_month == 'December' and 21 <= input_day <= 31 or input_month \
    == 'January' and 1 <= input_day <= 31 or input_month == 'February' \
    and 1 <= input_day <= 28 or input_month == 'March' and 1 \
    <= input_day <= 19:
    print('Winter')
```

Though, there are ways to make the solution more readable, pythonic and compact. For example, like this:

```
MONTHS = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June",
          "July", "August", "September", "October", "November",
          "December"]

BOUNDARIES = [((3, 20), (6, 20), "Spring"),
              ((6, 21), (9, 21), "Summer"),  # FIXED THE UPPER BOUNDARY
              ((9, 22), (12, 20), "Autumn"),
              ((12, 21), (12, 31), "Winter"),
              ((1, 1), (3, 19), "Winter")]

input_month = input()
input_day = int(input())

input_date = (MONTHS.index(input_month) + 1, input_day)

for lower, upper, season in BOUNDARIES:
    if lower <= input_date <= upper:
        print(season)
        break
```

or (less efficient way) like this:

```
SEASONS = {"Spring": [
               ("March", (20, 32)),
               ("June", (1, 21)),
                ],
           "Summer": [
               ("June", (21, 31)),
               ("September", (1, 31)),
                ],
           "Autumn": [
               ("September", (22, 31)),
               ("December", (1, 21)),
                ],
           "Winter": [
               ("December", (21, 32)),
               ("January", (1, 32)),
               ("February", (1, 29)),
               ("March", (1, 20)),
                ]
           }

input_month = input()
input_day = int(input())

for season in SEASONS:
    for month, day_ranges in SEASONS[season]:
        if input_month == month and input_day in range(*day_ranges):
            print(season)
    else:
        continue
    break
```

Comment: I was thinking that a dict might be better, but I couldn't figure out how to do this without spelling out each value. Makes sense why I couldn't figure it out now as we haven't covered the range function in this class yet.

Comment: Would you be willing to give me an example of how the range and dictionary functions can be combined with correct syntax in a situation such as this?

Comment: @Drkdeibs I updated the answer. If you have questions, feel free to ask :)

Comment: PS: @Drkdeibs range function and dictionary are absolutely different things which have nothing to do with each other (see the last solution in my answer). `integer in range(start, end)` (note there are [other usages](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-range-function/) also) checks if the integer is between start and end - 1, both inclusive. While `dict` just stores key-value pairs.

Answer (score 0):

You first forget to use semicolons at end of every if and else statements.
And next things if u want to continue your statement in next line use "\" at line end.
i m mentioning a example below.

```
if (input_month == 'June') and (21 <= input_day <= 30) \
  or (input_month == 'September') and (1 <= input_day <= 30):
print('Summer')
```

Answer (score 0):

This the correct and working code for your solution.

```
input_month = input()
input_day = int(input())

# input reading for spring
if ((input_month == 'March') and (20 <= input_day <= 31)) or ((input_month == 'June') and (1 <= input_day <= 20)):
    print('Spring')

# input reading for summer
elif (input_month == 'June') and (21 <= input_day <= 30) or (input_month == 'September') and (1 <= input_day <= 30):
    print('Summer')

# input reading for Autumn
elif (input_month == 'September') and (22 <= input_day <= 30) or (input_month == 'December') and (1 <= input_day <= 20):
    print('Autumn')

# input reading for winter
elif (input_month == 'December') and (21 <= input_day <= 31) or (input_month == 'January') and (
        1 <= input_day <= 31) or (input_month == 'February') and (1 <= input_day <= 28) or (
        input_month == 'March') and (1 <= input_day <= 19):
    print('Winter')
```